# How to fix the Onedrive songs' names bug?

Tags: 8.1, music, onedrive, sd-card

I've been using the OneDrive songs in the Music app for a long time. But today a bug occurred.
After adding some songs into the cloud, I tried to play them; while pressing the volume buttons, the song's name appear as a bunch of numbers and something that looks like hex code, and then ".mp3". This is the actual name of the stored file.

It does not occur inside of the app. Only when pressing the volume buttons. But I think this happened because of a change I made: because of the remaining space, I put all the kind of data to be stored in the SD card. Not the previous, but the new data. How can I fix this?

Edit 1:
I moved a bunch of songs to SD and then updated it (creating a new folder). No success. Now even the moved files are showing up that way. The problem really is the SD card.

Edit 2: Added some music to the cloud and the added ones looked normal. Let's see what we can get from that.

Edit 3: I tried to delete everything and re-download... and it worked! But is there any better solution? Because if I wanted to switch to phone storage I'd be really scared to have all this trouble.

Edit 4 (yes, 4!): Worked... partially. Some songs are still that way. Probably some Xbox Music bug. Heh, "news".

**Current solution: Windows Phone 10 Preview, Groove Music.**

Comment: The music app store the downloaded music from OneDrive in the Music/Music cache folder. Deleting that folder than redownloading again may could have solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the properties of a music file using your computer. Sync the Music folder with your computer then right-click the song, select **Properties** and then go to **Details**. Under Details you can edit a lot of information stored in the file, that will later show up and also help Groove match your music against the library and download more information, like album art.